# value of (*p-1) when p points to an array

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learn about pointers of C/C++ recently, but there's a pointer question confused me.

Code below, assume p is a int pointer to an array a.

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
printf("(*p-1)=%d\n",(*p-1)); // 32765
```

I thought `(int*)(&a+1)` is equal to end address of array a. And p points to the address.

But why `(*p-1)` shows 32765? I even don't know the value of *p.

Comment: maybe you want `*(p-1)`?

Comment: Why will *(p-1) = 32765?

Comment: @pmg I doubt OP *wants* that, it seems like a pretty convoluted way of getting the last element of an array, and it’s UB anyway.

Comment: `*(p - 1)` is not the same as `(*p - 1)`

Comment: Undefined behavior for out of bounds access.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `&a` is a pointer to the array denoted by `a`, i.e. its type is `int (*)[5]` (“a pointer to an array of `int` of size 5”).

`&a + 1` adds `sizeof a` bytes to the offset of the address of `a`. The result is thus a pointer to an array of size 5 that’s located adjacently in memory directly behind `a`.

However, as far as C is concerned, *this array does not exist*, because nothing created it (via e.g. `malloc`). You are allowed to create a pointer to it (because a pointer one-past-`a` is allowed), but you are not allowed to dereference it. Doing so causes undefined behaviour, the effect of which is generally unknowable.

Since you’ve declared `p` as `int *p` rather than `int (*p)[5]`, it now points to the first element of the non-existent array at address `&a + 1`. This is allowed: pointers to a type are allowed to alias pointers to an array of that type. But that array *still* doesn’t exist, so you are not allowed to dereference `p` any more than you are allowed to dereference the array at `&a + 1`.

Yet `*p - 1` (which is the same as `(*p) - 1`!) does just that: it tries to dereference `p` and subtract 1 from the dereferenced value. Since this isn’t allowed the implementation has license to do “whatever it likes”. In your case, the implementation happens to return a random, meaningless value. Alternatively, your code could also have crashed or done something completely different, and seemingly unrelated.

There are a range of advanced tools to catch such errors. One tool is [Google’s AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). It’s built into GCC so, if you are compiling your application with GCC, you can use it by passing the flag `-fsanitize=address` to the compiler:

```sh
cc -fsanitize=address -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror ub.c -o ub
```

Now when you execute your application you’ll get a (literally) colourful error message:

```
⟩⟩⟩ ./ub
=================================================================
==81812==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffeed29b314 at pc 0x000102964cd7 bp 0x7ffeed29b2d0 sp 0x7ffeed29b2c8
READ of size 4 at 0x7ffeed29b314 thread T0
    #0 0x102964cd6 in main ub.c:6
    #1 0x7fff602883d4 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x163d4)

Address 0x7ffeed29b314 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 52 in frame
    #0 0x102964b8f in main ub.c:3

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 52) 'a' (line 4) <== Memory access at offset 52 overflows this variable
…
```

There is more, but this is the gist: there’s an error in `ub.c` in line 6 (the `printf`) line, which is caused by a memory access that overflows a variable `a` which was declared in a stack frame (~ function scope) that starts in line 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
printf("(*p-1)=%d\n",(*p-1)); // 32765
```

Here's my analysis:
Let's assume size of int is 4 bytes & assume start address of array a is 1000, then elements in array will be stored as

Values vs addresses: 1(1000), 2(1004), 3(1008), 4(1012), 5(1016)

The next operation in your statement is

```
int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
```

Now, array index (which in this case is a) being pointing to 1st element of array it breaks down to

```
int *p = (int*)(&a[0]+1);
```

So, if we go with address mapping as described above, p should point to
location: 1000(address of a[0]) + 1 = 1001, which is happening in your case

How to get end address of array a?

```
int *p = (int*)(&a[4]);//points to end of array a
int *p = (int*)(&a+sizeof(a));//This also points to end of array a
```